# Ember BelongsTo Assertion Failed

Tags: ember.js, belongs-to

Consider the following 2 models: car and owner

I have a car record with the current owner (bob jones)
and I have a owner record (bob jones) with details... address, phone etc.

In my car form (car model), I have this:

```
export default Model.extend({
    "owner_id": DS.belongsTo('owner'),
    "year": attr(''),
    "model": attr(''),
    "make": attr('')
})
```

Stored on the DB end, is the ID '12345', corresponding to the Bob Jones owner record.

When I load up the car record (2015 Jaguar), it will also connect to the Bob Jones record which tells me his phone, address etc.  For example, if I print out

```
{{owner_id.id}} - {{owner_id.name}}
```

I will show:

**12345 - Bob Jones**

My question is, what happens if I change owners of the car.  If I select the dropdown list

```
{{my-select
    name="owner_id"
    content=ownerList
    selection=owner_id.id
    prompt="select an owner"
    required=true
}}
```

From this component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  content: [],
  prompt: null,
  optionValuePath: 'value',
  optionLabelPath: 'label',

  init: function () {
    this._super(...arguments);
    if (!this.get('content')) {
      this.set('content', []);
    }
  },

  actions: {
    change: function () {
      let selectedIndex = this.$('select')[0].selectedIndex;
      let content = this.get('content');

      // decrement index by 1 if we have a prompt
      let hasPrompt = !!this.get('prompt');
      let contentIndex = hasPrompt ? selectedIndex - 1 : selectedIndex;
      let _selection = content[contentIndex];

      this.sendAction('willChangeAction', _selection);

      if (this.get('optionValuePath')) {
        this.set('selection', _selection[this.get('optionValuePath')]);
      } else {
        this.set('selection', _selection);
      }

      this.sendAction('didChangeAction', _selection);
    }
  }
});
```

and change the value... I get this error:

***A record's id cannot be changed once it is in the loaded state***

How do you go about updating the 2015 Jaguar car record to change the owner, and load in the details of the new owner?

Comment: What select component are you using? I'm curious because that changes how to correctly setup the component in my answer.

Comment: updated question to reflect the component code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing the id of the owner instead of changing the `owner_id` prop on the jaguar. I changed the `owner_id` prop to `owner` to help clarify what the belongsTo holds.

The general strategy I'm taking is to select the owner of the car, then pass that back up to the controller to save the car.

models/car.js

```
export default Model.extend({
    "owner": DS.belongsTo('owner'),
    // ...
})
```

routes/cars/car.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      car: this.store.find('car', params.id),
      ownerList: // however you get the owner list
    })
  }
})
```

controllers/cars/car.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions{
    ownerChanged(newOwner) {
      // If the select is setup properly, newOwner should be an instance of owner.
      const car = this.get('model.car');
      car.set('owner', newOwner);
      car.save
    }
  }
})
```

templates/cars/car.hbs.

```
{{my-select
    name="owner"
    content=model.ownerList
    selection=model.car.owner.id
    prompt="select an owner"
    required=true
    didChangeAction='ownerChanged'
}}
```

The code in the route's model hook is mostly there for clarity, if you're taking a different approach, adjust the names accordingly

Comment: In theory, it makes sense... however selection=model.car.owner.id  is relating to the car doc, having 'owner'... that belongs to the owner doc... and inside the owner doc is the id '12345'  selection='12345'  which does return the correct owner. (note that in the car doc, owner would already equal '12345' as the stored ID.  The moment I change the selection is where I get the error.  I guess I'm having a disconnect how you change the id of 'owner' and still store the new id in the car doc.  To me, changing owner (car doc) id, should resolve and find the owner doc for the new id.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because changing a model's related model entails setting the relationship attribute to a different model and not changing the id of the related model.

xcskier56 is right that you should declare your relationship as:

`"owner": DS.belongsTo('owner')`

It makes more sense because now you call `car.owner.id` or `car.owner.name` rather than `car.owner_id.id` or `car.owner_id.name`.

Now if you want to change the owner of a car, you cannot do `car.set('owner.id', newId);`. You have to change the model and not the id, like so: `car.set('owner', newOwner);`

And for using a select to change the owner, you can use select addons that support objects / models as options (ember-power-select), or make your own similar to xcskier56's suggestion.

Comment: Ahhh ok. Forgive me for the confusion. Thank you for clarifying.